# PHP: Why can't I use WHERE in this SQL query?

Tags: php, sql

Im having a problem with a sql query. This is the original function:

```
function selectAllSorted($active)
{
    return $this->selectObjects("SELECT bp.*, p.title as product_title
                                 FROM $this->_table bp 
                                 INNER JOIN ?_product p USING (product_id)
                                 ORDER BY 0+sort_order,p.title");
}
```

Which i modified it to look like this:

```
function selectAllSorted($active)
{
    return $this->selectObjects("SELECT bp.*, p.title as product_title
                                 FROM $this->_table bp
                                 WHERE product_id =$active
                                 INNER JOIN ?_product p USING (product_id)
                                 ORDER BY 0+sort_order,p.title");
}
```

But i get an unknown error and since i cant see the logs i cant pinpoint where it is or why is it wrong to use WHERE here.

This is how the function selectObjects is defined:

```
function selectObjects($sql, $param1 = null)
    {
        $args = func_get_args();
        $q = call_user_func_array(array($this->_db, 'queryResultOnly'), $args);
        $ret = array();
        while ($row = $this->_db->fetchRow($q))
        {
            $obj = new $this->_recordClass($this);
            $obj->fromRow($row);
            $ret[] = $obj;
        }
        return $ret;
    }
```

Can you guys figure out whats wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Move the `WHERE` clause and place it after the `JOIN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong - the `where` clause comes after the `join` clause(s):

```
function selectAllSorted($active)
{
    return $this->selectObjects("SELECT bp.*, p.title as product_title
                                 FROM $this->_table bp
                                 INNER JOIN ?_product p USING (product_id)
                                 WHERE bp.product_id =$active
                                 ORDER BY 0+sort_order,p.title");
}
```

Comment: It will probably be necessary to select product_id from one of the tables, i.e. `WHERE p.productid =...`, won't it?

Comment: @TomasPastircak yup, good catch! Added the `bp` prefix to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! That was fast! I though the order didnt matter.

Answer (score 0):

Join Query syntex is:

```
Select t1.* from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2  on t1.col1=t2.col1
where t1.col2> 0 and t2.col3>4
```

Now, your query look like :

```
function selectAllSorted($active)
{
    return $this->selectObjects("SELECT bp.*, p.title as product_title
                                 FROM $this->_table bp
                                 INNER JOIN ?_product p on pb.product_id=p.product_id
                                 WHERE bp.product_id =$active                                
                                 ORDER BY 0+sort_order,p.title");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was useful too.